# Equicontinuous curves on compact Riemannian manifold have uniform convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

Assuming $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. $\gamma_j:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ are equicontinuous curves, namely, there is constant $L$ such that
$$
d(\gamma_j(t_1),\gamma_j(t_2))\le L(t_2-t_1)
~~~~~~
\forall t_1\le t_2 \in [0,1],~~\forall \gamma_j\in\{\gamma_j\}
$$
And the length of $\gamma_j$ converge, assuming $\lim\limits_{j\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal l(\gamma_j)=h$ (this also means equicontinuous).   Then how to show $\{\gamma_j\}$ have uniform convergent subsequence ?

[Arzela-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem):  Consider a sequence of real-valued continuous functions $\{f_n \}, n \in N $ defined on a closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$ of the real line. If this sequence is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous, then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\},k ∈ N$ that converges uniformly.

Comment: Do you know the Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I find it in Wiki, and added it above.  I don't know how to translate it to the version on compact manifold. Seemly, the compact roughly equal to uniformly bounded.

Comment: Compact target implies that you have a uniformly bounded family of maps (every compact metric space is bounded).

Comment: And if you read a bit more you will find that AA holds for functions with values in a compact metric space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Thanks for your detailed tip. I was too blundering recently.